# How to display entity related errors in WPF 4.5 with INotifyDataErrorInfo?

Tags: wpf, validation, inotifydataerrorinfo

MSDN documentation states that `GetErrors` method should return entity related errors if propertyName is null or empty.

But debugging shows that propertyName is always the name of the proprty being validated.

What should I do to force WPF to ask for entity related errors?

**Update**

It looks like this is possible in silverlight where `ValidationSummary` control exists.

Comment: do you mean ValidatesOnDataErrors=true in wpf bindings?

Comment: No, I mean ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to the following question to get the answer:

[INotifyDataErrorInfo Entity-Level Validation. How to raise a Validation.Error event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650931/inotifydataerrorinfo-entity-level-validation-how-to-raise-a-validation-error-ev)

You only have to define a Validation.ErrorTemplate for the Grid for example and it should show that in case of an error!